# How to directly update reference models in mongodb by creating documents in another model?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Okay so I have 3 models in my API , Patient, Doctor and Reviews. I have referenced the Reviews model in the Doctor model. The idea is that a patient is able to post a review for a particular doctor using Review.create(). However, after the document is created, since the Review model is referenced in the Doctor model, the "reviews" property in the doctor model should be updated automatically too. Cant seem to get that to happen.

Patient Model:

```
const PatientSchema = new Schema<patientType>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a product name'],
        maxlength: 50,
        minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide an email'], 
        match: [
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'Please provide a valid email',
          ],
          unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["male", "female", "other"]
    },
    bloodtype: {
        type: String
    },
    appointments: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Booking',
        required: true
    }]
})
```

Doctor Model:

```
const DoctorSchema = new Schema<doctorType>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a product name'],
        maxlength: 50,
        minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide an email'], 
        match: [
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'Please provide a valid email',
          ],
          unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide a password'],
        minlength: 8
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
    },
    ticketPrice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1000,
        required: true
    },
    specialization: {
        type: String,
    },
    qualifications: {
        type: [Object],
    },
    experiences: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
    },
    about: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 4
    },
    reviews: [{                         //where i referenced the review model
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Review",
        required: true,
        default: []
    }],
    averageRating: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    totalRatings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    isApproved: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["pending", "approved", "cancelled"],
        default: 'pending'
    },
    appointments: [{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Booking',
        required: true
    }]
    
})
```

Reviews model:

```
const ReviewSchema = new Schema<reviewType>({
    doctor: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Doctor",
    },
    patient: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please add a review text'],
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        default: 0,
    },
},{ timestamps: true });
```

patient creating doctor review function:

```
const postDoctorReviews = async (req: MyUserRequest, res: Response) => {
    const {id: doctorId} = req.params
    const {patientId} = req.user

    const {text, rating} = req.body

    if(!text || !rating){
        throw new BadRequestError('Field cannot be empty')
    }

    const doctorReview = await Review.create({doctor: doctorId, patient: patientId, ...req.body})
    
    const doctor = await Doctor.findById(doctorId)
    doctor?.save()
    
    res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({doctorReview})  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the references are not updated automatically with `doctor?.save()`. You need to push the `Review._id` into the `Doctor.reviews` array manually.

Change this:

```js
const doctor = await Doctor.findById(doctorId)
doctor?.save()
```

To this:

```js
const doctor = await Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(doctorId,
{
   $push: {
      reviews: doctorReview._id
   }
},{new:true});
```